# Processing.org/Minim FFT Error

Tags: java, processing, minim

I'm trying to use the Minim FFT library, but when running an example sketch, I run into the the following issue:

```
The constructor FFT(int, float) is undefined.
```

I am guessing that this Java thinks I am trying to use some other constructor, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve it.

Heres the relevant part of the code:

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

FFT fft;
float[] buffer;
int bsize = 512;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 300, P3D);
  // create an FFT with a time-domain size the same as the size of buffer
  // it is required that these two values be the same
  // and also that the value is a power of two
  fft = new FFT(bsize, 44100);
  buffer = new float[bsize];
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your sketch?

Comment: It's SetFreq. I had thought that could be the problem, but no :(

Comment: That's odd, have you tried using any of the other minim classes? If so, did they work?

Comment: this above code compiles for me using 1.5.1, with no errors... Are you under 2.0x?

Comment: What version of Processing are you using ? I've tried your snippet in Processing 2.0b7 and it compiles with no problems.

Comment: This is using 2.06b on OSX 10.8. Some of the other examples work fine, so I am guessing minim is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly importing the FFT class:

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.FFT;
```

I'm not sure why this is required, but I was having the same problem and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Processing 2. The issue in my case was that the Processing sketch was named "FFT". This created a naming issue. Your first solution could be to create a new sketch that's renamed to something else. Alternatively, you could try including the package path when you instantiate your FFT object. For example: 
"ddf.minim.analysis.FFT"